# LaTeX Error: Environment DoxyRefList undefined. DoxyRefList

Tags: errors, pdftex, pdf, compiling

Im trying to generate pdf with doxygen. Already I have tex file generates, like "refman.tex". I can't compile with latex, or pdflatex. Here is the obtained error:

```
*latex refman.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
! LaTeX Error: Environment DoxyRefList undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \begin{DoxyRefList}

?*
```

Edit: doxygen: http://www.doxygen.nl/

Edit: added some code of "refman.tex"

```
\begin{DoxyRefList}
\item[\label{test__test000001}%
\hypertarget{test__test000001}{}%
Member \hyperlink{group__sldpc__fine__interleaver__top__test_ga3d668b96ab81f86ac7312b9bfe592abe}{T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-F} (\hyperlink{classSldpc__fine__interleaver__top__test__vm}{Sldpc\-\_\-fine\-\_\-interleaver\-\_\-top\-\_\-test\-\_\-vm}, T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-B\-A\-S\-I\-C\-\_\-\-B\-Y\-P\-A\-S\-S)]\hyperlink{group__sldpc__fine__interleaver__top__test_ga3d668b96ab81f86ac7312b9bfe592abe}{T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-F(\-Sldpc\-\_\-fine\-\_\-interleaver\-\_\-top\-\_\-test\-\_\-vm, T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-B\-A\-S\-I\-C\-\_\-\-B\-Y\-P\-A\-S\-S)}  
\item[\label{test__test000098}%
\hypertarget{test__test000098}{}%
Member \hyperlink{group__sldpc__fine__deinterleaver__top__test_ga778c0bdd3d0d50ec2d8e1081589e7c31}{T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-F} (\hyperlink{classSldpc__fine__deinterleaver__top__test__vm}{Sldpc\-\_\-fine\-\_\-deinterleaver\-\_\-top\-\_\-test\-\_\-vm}, T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-B\-Y\-P\-A\-S\-S\-\_\-\-Q\-A\-M64\-\_\-3kx5x32)]\hyperlink{group__sldpc__fine__deinterleaver__top__test_ga778c0bdd3d0d50ec2d8e1081589e7c31}{T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-F(\-Sldpc\-\_\-fine\-\_\-deinterleaver\-\_\-top\-\_\-test\-\_\-vm, T\-E\-S\-T\-\_\-\-B\-Y\-P\-A\-S\-S\-\_\-\-Q\-A\-M64\-\_\-3kx5x32)}  
.
.
.
\end{DoxyRefList}
```

Comment: Without any example code it is impossible to help. Not everyone even know that `doxygen` is.

Comment: Do you have a `doxygen.sty` in your directory there?

Comment: Yes. What is that file?